# how to get "Storage almost is full" notification in my app

Tags: ios

how to get "Storage almost is  full" notification in my app, and I can do suspend my download thread.

I have trid didReceiveMemoryWarning(AppDelegate), it failed.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the simulator feature to send a storage warning, to see if you defined things correctly?

Comment: No,I use ipad device.

Comment: What I'm saying is, run it in the simulator and use that function to make sure you've got the AppDelegate hook coded correctly.

Comment: I hook it as the follow:-(void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning");
}

Comment: And you've tested that with the simulator?

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing memory and storage here .

They are two different things.

Memory is the RAM and Storage is the "disk space".

So didReceiveMemoryWarning has nothing to do with "Storage almost full" –

You can check free disk space using

```
+ (NSString *)freeDiskSpace {
    long long freeSpace = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];
    return [self memoryFormatter:freeSpace];
}
```

However I am not sure when the warning fires